# Append value of XML attribute to value of Another attribute in same file

Tags: xml, parsing, xslt, xml-parsing

Given with the following xml file

```
<testsuites>
  <testsuite><testcase name="case 1" ><failure type="ERROR">Hello</failure></testcase></testsuite>
  <testsuite><testcase name="case 2" ><failure type="WARNING">Buddy</failure></testcase></testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

I want to append the failure type value to the name of test case. So value of failure in above xml is  "ERROR" and name of the testcase is "Case 1" the resultant name would be "[ERROR] Case 1". I want  to do it via shell scripts for all test cases.

Note: There can be multiple testcases with different failure type in same file.

Target XML document required is

```
<testsuites>
  <testsuite><testcase name="[ERROR] case 1" ><failure type="ERROR">Hello</failure></testcase></testsuite>
  <testsuite><testcase name="[WARNING] case 2" ><failure type="WARNING">Buddy</failure></testcase></testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

What I have tried so far is creating XSLT doc based on target XML and use that XSLT to produce target XML, but I am not able to achieve this till now.

My XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<testsuites>
    <xsl:for-each select="/testsuites/testsuite">
<testsuite>
 <xsl:for-each select="./testcase">
  <testcase>
   <xsl:variable name="name" select="./@name"/>
   <!-- The variable name can be used for further processing.  -->
   <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="$name"/></xsl:attribute>
    <failure>
     <xsl:value-of   select="./failure"/>
     <xsl:variable name="type" select="./failure/@type"/>
     <!-- The variable type can be used for further processing.  -->
     <xsl:attribute name="type"><xsl:value-of select="$type"/></xsl:attribute>
    </failure>
   </testcase>
</xsl:for-each>
</testsuite>
</xsl:for-each>
</testsuites>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to append the failure type value to the name of test case.

Should be quite simple:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="testcase/@name">
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="../failure/@type" />
        <xsl:text>] </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That works magically, Could you please write similar xsl for the following xml which is original         <testsuites disabled="0" errors="0" failures="7" tests="7" time="0.0">
<testsuite disabled="0" errors="0" failures="7" name="semgrep results" skipped="0" tests="7" time="0">
<testcase name="generic.secrets.security.detected-etc-shadow.detected-etc-shadow" classname="selftest/secrets/bad-secrets.txt" file="selftest/secrets/bad-secrets.txt" line="1">
<failure type="ERROR" message="linux shadow file detected">root::17431:0:99999:7::: </failure>
</testcase>
</testsuite>
</testsuites>

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how this is different. It seems to me that the same stylesheet could be used to produce a similar result. If not, and you are unable to make the necessary changes yourself, please post it as a new question.